# Wrong defined/boundless $g \rightarrow\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{g(\frac1n)}{2^n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Let's consider:

$$f\colon (C[0,1], \Vert\cdot \Vert_1) \ni g\rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{g(\frac1n)}{2^n}$$

I'm trying to check if this object is well defined.

where $\Vert f \Vert_1 = \int_0^1|f(t)|dt$

Let's take function $g(x) = e^{\frac1x}$

Then this sum above will be turned into:

$$f(g) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{e}{2})^n$$

But this sequence cannot converge, becuase $(\frac e2)^n \rightarrow \infty, n \rightarrow \infty$.

So - I just found a function that $f(\text{that_function}) = \infty$.

Am I proved that funcional $f$ is wrongly defined or I just proved that $f$ it's boundless ?

My queries are derived from the fact that in my way of thinking I haven't used $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ anywhere.

Comment: $e^{1/x}$ is not defined at $0$, so it is neither bounded nor in $C([0,1])$. Also, you need to define $|| \cdot ||_1$, especially if it is not the $\sup$ norm.

Comment: Ohh you're right I updated my question by adding definiotion of norm

Comment: Could you just give me a hand by pointing if I'm going in right direction ? i.e. finding this specific example will show that functional is boundless or wrong defined ?

Comment: Your sums use $i$ as an index, but then an expression which contains an $n$ but no $i$. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ belongs to $V=(\mathcal C([0,1], \mathbb R), \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$, $g$ is continuous and therefore bounded on the compact segment $[0,1]$. The series

$$f(g) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{g(\frac1n)}{2^n}$$ is absolutely convergent and convergent. Conclusion: $f$ is defined on $V$.

*Note: the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ has nothing to do regarding the question of $f$ being well defined or not. The norm would obviously play a role on questions like the continuity of the functional $f$.*

Comment: Okay get it! Just please tell me how did you get that this series is absolutely convergent or convergent

Comment: Because $\sum_n 1/2^n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Okay that's true but how it proves that for any function $g$ series $\sum_n \frac{g(\frac1n)}{2^n}$ converges ?

Comment: If we have $(a_n)$ such that $\sum_n a_n$ converges it doesn't tell us that $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converges for any $(b_n)$ right ? I just do not quite see which other property you used

Comment: Come on! As $\vert g(x) \vert \le M$ for $x \in [0,1]$ as $g$ is bounded, you get $\left\vert \frac{g(\frac1n)}{2^n} \right\vert \le M/2^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: thanks for your time ;)) now I understand